# Large UPDATE [...] SELECT FROM causes parallel UPDATE/DELETE to die

Tags: mysql, select, locking, sql-update, table-locking

I'm trying to explain my problem by examples. I've a long running statement like

```
UPDATE <table_A>
INNER JOIN <table_B> ON [...]
LEFT JOIN <table_C> ON [...]
LEFT JOIN <table_D> ON [...]
LEFT JOIN <table_E> ON [...]
SET <table_A>.<col_A>=X
WHERE <table_A>.<col_A>=Y AND COALESCE(<table_C>.<id>,<table_D>.<id>,<table_E>.<id> IS NULL
```

This statement runs on big tables (two of them contain 7+ million rows per table). The update runs 3-5 minutes. In another sessions there is done in high concurrency

```
UPDATE <table_C> SET <col_A>=Z WHERE <id> IN ([...])
```

or

```
DELETE FROM <table_C> WHERE <id> IN ([...])
```

When the big `UPDATE` runs, then these concurrent `UPDATE` and `DELETES` die with lockwait timeout or deadlocks after one or two minutes. All `JOIN` columns are indexed (standard indexes).
I've already tried to do

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
[BIG UPDATE];
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

but that doesn't help. Data consistency on `<table_A>` is not so important (it's no problem if it contains rows which do not exist in `<table_C>`...`<table_E>` anymore). The most important is, that the small `UPDATE`/`DELETE`s on `<table_C>`...`<table_E>` are being processed.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to make such a big updates on a live database. You can break down your big update into several smaller, for example.

Comment: Thats no option for me, because I have to know that a "product_id" has to be in none of tables `<table_C>`...`<table_E>`. I've tried your suggestion already, but the largest table of them contains 7+ million rows and thats enough to cause the lockwait timeouts (regardless of the fact if the other two tables were also `JOIN`ed)

Comment: Check if my answer is different from what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's generally a bad idea to run updates this big on a live database, I suggest you break down your big update.

Here is not the most optimized way to do it, but i'm sure you'll manage to optimize it yourself.

Run in loop:

1. `SELECT Id, ColA FROM TableA ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET (iteration)*10`
2. Second loop, take rows from previous result where `tableA.colA=Y`
   2.1. `SELECT Id FROM TableB WHERE ID=id_from_current_iteration`
   2.2. `SELECT Id FROM TableC WHERE ID=id_from_current_iteration`
   2.3 If both previous queries returned null go to the next step, otherwise proceed to the next iteration
   2.4 `UPDATE TableA SET ColA=X WHERE ID=id_from_current_iteration`

In other words - **avoid joins**.
This will take longer than a single update, but it will work.
First step to optimize it will be batching queries.

Comment: Ok, you've split up the `JOIN`s, that's not my intention but should solve the problem in theory, so your answer is accepted. The problem occurs due to the fact that I combine `UPDATE` with `JOIN`s, which locks the rows. I've change the `UPDATE` to loop over `id` in steps of 10,000 now. This runs for 2-3 seconds for each loop and my experience is much better now.